# Is an irreducible regular algebraic curve, connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Motivated by [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211188/two-limit-cycles-which-lie-on-the-same-leaf) we ask:

Assume that $H(x,y)$ is  a real polynomial which is irreducible as a complex polynomial. Is it true to say that $H^{-1}(0)$  ($H:\mathbb{C}^{2} \to \mathbb{C}$) is  a  connected subset of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$?

Moreover what is an example of a connected regular curve in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ which intersection with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ contains at least 2 distinct closed curve?

By "closed curve" I mean a simple Jordan curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The question has nothing to do with algebraic geometry but is pure topology: every irreducible topological space is connected.
Indeed, by definition  an irreducible space $X$ is not  the union of two closed strict subsets of $X$. 
Hence *a fortiori* it is not a union of two **disjoint** closed strict subsets of $X$, which by definition of "connected" proves that $X$ is connected.

2) The curve $C$ given by $y^2 =x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ in $\mathbb C^2$ is smooth and irreducible hence connected.
Its real trace $C\cap \mathbb R^2$ however has two compact connected components, each homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: either I misunderstood or you meant in the last sentence of 1) that $X$ is *connected* (i.e. remove the word "not").

Comment: Dear @quantum, you are perfectly right and I have corrected my typo (i.e. suppressed the word *not*). Thank you very much for your vigilance.

Comment: Note that this argument only works in the Zariski topology. In the real topology, an algebraic curve defined by an irreducible polynomial is not irreducible in the topological sense.

Answer (score 2):

$H^{-1}(0)$ is clearly the curve defined by $H(x,y)=0$ and any irreducible variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is connected. For the second question, elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ are connected, but can have two connected components over $\mathbb{R}$. For example, consider the curve $y^2=x^3-x$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ this curve is connected since the equation is irreducible. But over reals, since the map to the $x$-axis is proper, suffices to show that the image is not connected. But the image consists of $x$ such that $x^3-x\geq 0$, since it must have a square root. Easy to check that these have two pieces, $x\geq 1$ and $-1\leq x\leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. Is there an irreducible polynomial such that the real variete consist at least 2 distinct closed curve?(As  I asked in my question). Moreever where is  a proof of  connected-ness of irreducible complex curve?

Comment: For the first, my example above works, as I said. You can also consider the rectangular hyperbola $xy=1$. It is connected over complex numbers, but has two components over reals. For a proof of connectedness, you can look it up, for example, in the book of Shafarevich.

Comment: I try to more explain about my question. By closed curve i mean a curve homeomorphic to circle. Not "close" as "no acumulation point". So i search for an irreducible polynomial H whth real cooeficient such that the real variete H=0  has at least two disjoint simple Jordan curve. y^2=x^3-x is not proper and does not satisfy this condition. I search for closed curve since I am motivated by limit cycles, as i explained in MO link